# How to suggest to users that they may need to change one of their email addresses from the default?

Tags: website-design, forms, input-fields

As part of account management users can set their Primary email, as well as the email used for other services (Google & Apple). These are required for the system to work.

For many users these will be identical, but others will have different emails for each. Currently all 3 default to the email registered with. The email change form is on an account management page with 3-4 other similar mini-forms.

The descriptive text changes on dropdown change, the action button only enables when both fields are filled in correctly, and the email field has a placeholder of the current value.

Default view:
[image]

Dropdown arrow pressed:
[image]

Another option selected:
[image]

The current system seems pretty straightforward to me, but user feedback suggested it was confusing, and didn't make it clear that other email addresses could be configured.

Initial ideas were some sort of "have you checked your other email addresses?" reminder, but I'd rather design it obviously enough that the users know they *may* need to change emails without explicit guidance.

Advice very much appreciated!

Comment: Is this a problem about getting users to this account management page? (this is what the title of the question makes it sound like) or is it about facilitating the changes when they're looking at this page? (this is what the mockups make it look like)

Comment: It's about facilitating the changes once they're on the acc management page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consider breaking out the inputs to improve visibility and discoverability**

*Users don't edit the emails because only those who investigate the dropdown know that other email types exist*

While you may be saving space by combining the inputs, you're not really streamlining the interaction. You mainly succeed in hiding the fact that there are multiple email types from all but those curious enough click around.

By breaking out the inputs into separate sections, you enable an experience along the following lines -- [Scans] "Email addresses, Primary email, Apple Email, don't have an Apple email, oh, but I do have a different Google email" [focuses on Google Email section] [reads instructive copy explaining why one should update Google email].--

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYEhMg.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Definitely works much better, thank you! First draft: https://i.imgur.com/DxwXudH.png

Comment: Oh, didn't notice you also swapped the email + password fields. Much better, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I would display the 3 email fields at once (no drop-down). And leave the change password button and the current password field only once.

And a label explaining that for security reason they need to enter their password again would avoid confusions (they might think they current password is not set in the system).

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHSnue.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>